# Compute a special multiple integral

Tags: multiple-integral

Let a function $f(x)$ be continuous and strictly positive on $[0, 1]$.
How to compute the following integral : $$\idotsint_{[0, 1]^n} \frac{f(x_1) + \dots + f(x_k)}{f(x_1) + \dots + f(x_n)} \,dx_1\cdots dx_n, ~k = 1,2,\ldots, n$$

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:
$$
\begin{align}
& \idotsint_{[0, 1]^n} \frac{f(x_1) + \dots + f(x_k)}{f(x_1) + \dots + f(x_n)} \,dx_1\cdots dx_n \\[10pt]
= {} & \idotsint_{[0, 1]^n} \frac{f(x_1)}{f(x_1) + \dots + f(x_n)} \,dx_1\cdots dx_n + \cdots \cdots \\[6pt]
& \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad {} \cdots \cdots + \idotsint_{[0, 1]^n} \frac{f(x_k)}{f(x_1) + \dots + f(x_n)} \,dx_1\cdots dx_n.
\end{align}
$$
Then I'd ask whether there's a difference between the values of the $k$ terms in that last sum of integrals. If not, then the sum is just $k$ times the first term in the sum of $k$ terms. And if $k=n$, then you have
$$
\idotsint_{[0, 1]^n} \frac{f(x_1) + \dots + f(x_n)}{f(x_1) + \dots + f(x_n)} \,dx_1\cdots dx_n = \idotsint_{[0, 1]^n} 1 \,dx_1\cdots dx_n,
$$
and that's easy to evaluate. So each of the integrals in that sum of integrals would be $1/n$ times the integral that's easy to evaluate, so finally we'd get $k/n$ times the integral that's easy to evaluate.

Comment: What if there is no difference between the values of the k terms in that sum of integrals?

Comment: @Parket : As I said, that means the sum is just $k$ times one of the integrals.